# Can more than one person catch the same Pokemon on pokemon Go?

Tags: pokemon-go

I live in Brasil and pokemonGo is still not available here.  I would like to know if multiple people can catch the same pokemon when its spawns near both players.  For example, when the Vaporeon spawend in central park, was only one person able to catch it or was it available for everyone for a limited time?